# Where can I find a simulator for a multimeter/LCR meter?

Tags: simulation

In my Laboratory Reports, I often need to justify the rounding of my calculations. For example if I find that \$V_{eff}=23.401\$, I will round it off as \$V_{eff}=23.4\$ in my reports.
For this, I often need to justify these approximations. One solution which I found was to illustrate the result with a screenshot of my calculator. I am using a SHARP EL-506T and SHARP provides a simulator for PC use here: (http://www.sharp-calculators.com/en/id/127-downloads
To justify my calculations, I often include in my reports a screenshot of the calculations from the PC simulator. The result looks like the following:

[image: calculation_screenshot]

For example, I may use the above screenshot to justify my rounding of delta where I will take \$\Delta=-0.22\$.
Now, I also need to do the same illustration for multimeters and LCR meters. For instance, we are using a **DER-EE DE 5000** LCR Meter in our circuit lab and I desperately need a simulator for these kind of devices as well so that I can justify the rounding which I make. Although I have found the manual of the device here at [iet-labs](https://www.ietlabs.com/pdf/Manuals/DE_5000_im.pdf), I thouroughly searched the internet for an LCR meter simulator but in vain.

[image: der-ee_de5000]

The above picture was copy-pasted from the DER-EE DE5000 PDF Manual from IET Labs website. I really want to find a simulator for an LCR Meter so that I can include a screenshot which looks similar to those figures found in the Manual. Does anybody have an idea where I may find such? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect such a simulator to do? If you just want images, why not take that one with all the segments lit and manually edit it in your image editor of choice?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE as regarding being valid for this site. It's also a shopping question. Use javascript and HTML canvas to automate one.

Comment: @Hearth Actually I haven't thought of that! That may work perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka You are free proceed as you see fit. But honestly, I find it really annoying that when I am trying my best to explain a real-world problem, people of your kind rush to close my questions. I do not know what makes this **not about EE** or that it is a **shopping question**? Serioulsy? There is not a single word in my question which encourages Advertisement of these products or a something such as comparing prices, etc. I am just using devices which are avalaible to me (from my school Lab) and most of these devices have BRAND NAMES. I just used the Brands for description purposes!

Comment: @billyandriam calm yourself. You asked *"Does anybody have an idea where I may find such? "* and that is a shopping question i.e. where can I find such and such a thing. I also was polite enough to give you a hint as to how you might make one (using js and canvas). So please don't be annoyed with me if you ask a question that is off-topic. Site rule = *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: ... or just don't round your calculations. Rounding is one certain way of propagating and compounding errors.

Comment: @Andyaka academic settings tend to stress the concept of significant figures and penalize answers which provide more precision than is actually knowable, but yes, one needs to be careful about intermediate steps.  More problematically, the question is fatally flawed in thinking that a screenshot of an instrument somehow justifies any of this - **to justify the precision of a result, *explain in words* what information is knowable and why.**

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for the explanation. I get your point now.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You know, we are working with ideal models in the prelab part. Then, we have to conduct a lab with real-world values and have to measure the component values with a multimeter and an LCR meter. After that, we must explain the discrepancy in the error between the calculations made with ideal parts and the actual values found in the lab. So, I was thinking that a screenshot of a measuring instrument would serve as a justification to my values because our TAs know that students fiddle with values and deliberately misreport measured values in order to minimize the errors.

Comment: No, a screenshot is meaningless and reflects only the decisions made by the person dreaming up the virtual instrument - take a minute to understand that in the real world you can buy meters of varying precision and calibration.  The only thing that would be meaningful is your words explaining a decision on the basis of knowable physical facts and uncertainties.  Don't place magical trust in mysterious boxes, take time to understand what is actually going on, and then explain your unerstanding as part of your assignment answer.

Comment: how does the screenshot you posted justify your choice to round delta ( Δ=−0.22 )? ... it seems that you are trying to achieve a goal that is based on a misunderstanding

Comment: @jsotola I used the symmetrical rounding technique for rounding negative numbers. Is it wrong in some sense?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to justify rounding with a screen shot of the meter. You need to justify rounding with how many digits you have chosen to work to. If it's appropriate to work to 5 digits, then rounding 23.401 to 23.4 is wrong.

A justification for the number of digits would be useful, which may be the noise level of the measurement, or the precision level you want to achieve, or what the assignment has told you to work to. In other words, what does appropriate mean in this particular context.

The number of digits for rounding should not be decided based on what the meter is reading.

There is a different issue with whether the rounding was done correctly. Are you aware that there are different methods for rounding? For instance round 0.5 up is a popular one, but round 0.5 to even is arguably better, being unbiased. I was in a situation a few years ago where the official rounding method was truncate. No matter that it wasn't the 'best' way to do it, that's the way the organisation wanted it done.